# Installing cordova using cmd , gives error windows 7

Tags: node.js, cordova, installation

using the below link to install phone gap ... on windows 7

http://chrisbitting.com/2014/01/06/installing-starting-with-phonegap-on-windows-for-cross-platform-mobile-development/

I have installed node-js  using Windows 7 . using cmd , i am installing cordova, with following command.

```
npm install –g cordova
```

the cmd screen shows

```
C:\Users\welcome>npm install -g cordova
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install C:\Users\welcome\-g
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\n
pm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\welcome\-g
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT, open 'C:\Users\welcome\-g'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\welcome\npm-debug.log

C:\Users\welcome>
```

the log file shows

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '–g',
1 verbose cli   'cordova' ]
2 info using npm@2.10.1
3 info using node@v0.12.4
4 verbose config Skipping project config: C:\Users\welcome/.npmrc. (matches userconfig)
5 verbose install initial load of C:\Users\welcome\package.json
6 verbose readDependencies loading dependencies from C:\Users\welcome\package.json
7 silly cache add args [ '–g', null ]
8 verbose cache add spec –g
9 silly cache add args [ 'cordova', null ]
10 verbose cache add spec cordova
11 silly cache add parsed spec { raw: '–g',
11 silly cache add   scope: null,
11 silly cache add   name: null,
11 silly cache add   rawSpec: '–g',
11 silly cache add   spec: 'C:\\Users\\welcome\\–g',
11 silly cache add   type: 'local' }
12 silly cache add parsed spec { raw: 'cordova',
12 silly cache add   scope: null,
12 silly cache add   name: 'cordova',
12 silly cache add   rawSpec: '',
12 silly cache add   spec: '*',
12 silly cache add   type: 'range' }
13 silly addNamed cordova@*
14 verbose addNamed "*" is a valid semver range for cordova
15 silly addNameRange { name: 'cordova', range: '*', hasData: false }
16 silly mapToRegistry name cordova
17 silly mapToRegistry using default registry
18 silly mapToRegistry registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
19 silly mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
20 verbose addNameRange registry:https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova not in flight; fetching
21 error addLocal Could not install C:\Users\welcome\–g
22 verbose request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
23 verbose request no auth needed
24 info attempt registry request try #1 at 12:29:17 PM
25 verbose request id 9ade987e28dcb26a
26 verbose etag "3DHF9YXEVOORVB2MTFGU3SZT8"
27 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
28 http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
29 silly get cb [ 304,
29 silly get   { date: 'Tue, 16 Jun 2015 06:59:14 GMT',
29 silly get     via: '1.1 varnish',
29 silly get     'cache-control': 'max-age=60',
29 silly get     etag: '"3DHF9YXEVOORVB2MTFGU3SZT8"',
29 silly get     age: '55',
29 silly get     connection: 'keep-alive',
29 silly get     'x-served-by': 'cache-sin6924-SIN',
29 silly get     'x-cache': 'HIT',
29 silly get     'x-cache-hits': '1',
29 silly get     'x-timer': 'S1434437954.319732,VS0,VE1',
29 silly get     vary: 'Accept' } ]
30 verbose etag https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova from cache
31 verbose get saving cordova to C:\Users\welcome\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\registry.npmjs.org\cordova\.cache.json
32 silly addNameRange number 2 { name: 'cordova', range: '*', hasData: true }
33 silly addNameRange versions [ 'cordova',
33 silly addNameRange   [ '0.0.1',
33 silly addNameRange     '0.0.2',
33 silly addNameRange     '0.0.3',
33 silly addNameRange     '0.0.4',
33 silly addNameRange     '0.0.5',
33 silly addNameRange     '0.0.6',
33 silly addNameRange     '0.0.7',
33 silly addNameRange     '0.0.8',
33 silly addNameRange     '0.0.9',
33 silly addNameRange     '0.1.0',
33 silly addNameRange     '0.1.1',
33 silly addNameRange     '0.1.2',
33 silly addNameRange     '0.1.3',
33 silly addNameRange     '0.1.4',
33 silly addNameRange     '0.1.5',
33 silly addNameRange     '0.1.6',
33 silly addNameRange     '0.1.7',
33 silly addNameRange     '0.1.8',
33 silly addNameRange     '0.1.9',
33 silly addNameRange     '0.1.10',
33 silly addNameRange     '0.1.11',
33 silly addNameRange     '0.1.12',
33 silly addNameRange     '0.1.13',
33 silly addNameRange     '0.1.14',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.2.0',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.3.0',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.3.1',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.3.2',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.3.3',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.3.5',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.3.6',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.4.0',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.4.1',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.4.2',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.4.3',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.4.4',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.4.5',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.4.6',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.4.7',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.4.8',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.4.9',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.4.10',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.5.0',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.5.2',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.5.3',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.5.4',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.5.5',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.6.0',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.6.1',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.6.2',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.7.0-rc.1',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.7.1-rc.1',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.7.2',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.7.3',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.7.4',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.8.0',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.8.1',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.8.2',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.8.3',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.8.4',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.8.5',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.8.6',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.8.7',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.8.8',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.8.9',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.8.10',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.8.11',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.8.12',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.8.13',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.8.14',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.8.15',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.8.16',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.8.17',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.8.18',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.8.19',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.8.20',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.8.21',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.8.22',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.8.23',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.8.24',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.8.25',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.9.0',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.9.1',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.9.2',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.9.3',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.9.4',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.9.5',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.9.6',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.9.7',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.0.0-rc1',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.0.0-rc1-1',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.0.0-rc1-3',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.0.0',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.0.1',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.0.2',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.0.3',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.0.4',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.0.5',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.0.6',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.0.7',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.0.8',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.0.9',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.0.10',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.1.0-0.1.0',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.1.0-0.2.0',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.2.0-rc.1',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.2.0-0.1.0',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.2.0-0.2.0',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.2.0-0.3.0',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.2.0-0.4.0',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.3.0-rc.1',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.3.0-0.1.1',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.3.1-0.1.2',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.9.0-rc1',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.3.1-0.3.0',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.3.1-0.3.1',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.3.1-0.4.1',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.3.1-0.4.2',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.4.0-0.1.0',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.4.0-0.1.1',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.4.0-0.1.2',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.4.0-0.1.3',
33 silly addNameRange     '0.0.0-fake',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.4.1-0.1.0',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.5.0-0.2.0',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.5.0-0.2.1',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.5.0-0.2.2',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.5.0-0.2.3',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.5.0-0.2.4',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.5.0-0.2.6',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.5.0-0.2.7',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.6.0-0.2.8',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.6.0-0.2.9',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.6.1-0.2.10',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.6.3-0.2.11',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.6.3-0.2.12',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.6.3-0.2.13',
33 silly addNameRange     '4.0.0',
33 silly addNameRange     '4.0.1',
33 silly addNameRange     '4.1.0',
33 silly addNameRange     '4.1.1',
33 silly addNameRange     '4.1.2',
33 silly addNameRange     '4.1.3-nightly.2014.10.21',
33 silly addNameRange     '4.2.0',
33 silly addNameRange     '4.3.0',
33 silly addNameRange     '5.0.0',
33 silly addNameRange     '4.3.1',
33 silly addNameRange     '5.1.1' ] ]
34 silly addNamed cordova@5.1.1
35 verbose addNamed "5.1.1" is a plain semver version for cordova
36 silly cache afterAdd cordova@5.1.1
37 verbose afterAdd C:\Users\welcome\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\cordova\5.1.1\package\package.json not in flight; writing
38 verbose afterAdd C:\Users\welcome\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\cordova\5.1.1\package\package.json written
39 verbose stack Error: ENOENT, open 'C:\Users\welcome\–g'
39 verbose stack     at Error (native)
40 verbose cwd C:\Users\welcome
41 error Windows_NT 6.1.7600
42 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "–g" "cordova"
43 error node v0.12.4
44 error npm  v2.10.1
45 error path C:\Users\welcome\–g
46 error code ENOENT
47 error errno -4058
48 error enoent ENOENT, open 'C:\Users\welcome\–g'
48 error enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
48 error enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
49 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]
```

any one know what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

for some reason ... running this

```
 npm install npm -g
```

and then running

```
npm install –g cordova
```

seemed to do the trick ....

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3624 - got it from this link